# Gas limit vs gasleft() for failed call

Tags: gas

I am having the following piece of code in my smart contract:

```
uint256 gasBefore = gasleft();
externalContract.call.gas(gasLimit)(abi.encodeWithSignature(
  "myFunction(uint256,uint256)", param1, param2
));
uint256 gasAfter = gasleft();
uint256 gasSpent = gasBefore.sub(gasAfter);

emit GasSpentEvent(gasLimit, gasSpent);
```

The gas needed to call `myFunction` is `60630`. When I set `gasLimit` to `60630`, then `gasSpent == gasLimit`.

However, if I set `gasLimit` to any lower value `gasSpent != gasLimit`. What's even more interesting the difference between `gasSpent` and `gasLimit` is different every time I change `gasSpent`:

```
gasLimit: 20000 -> 21145 :gasSpent (diff 1145)
gasLimit: 20010 -> 21154 :gasSpent (diff 1144)
gasLimit: 20020 -> 21164 :gasSpent (diff 1144)
gasLimit: 20100 -> 21243 :gasSpent (diff 1143)
```

Why `gasSpent != gasLimit` only for failed calls? Why the difference between `gasLimit` and `gasSpent` changes? Is there any reliable way to calculate the gas spent on `call`?

Comment: Interesting! Since gas limit is set to below the gas required your function is always reverting, so it will consume at most your gas limit. My guess is the solidity compiler write some code around call and that code varies slightly.